# How to get the count of 2 values in the same column, in the same table?

Tags: sql, join

I have a dataset about chess games, and in the winner column there are only 2 values: 'white' and 'black'. I want to show COUNT(winner) as WHITE_WINS and COUNT(winner) as BLACK_WINS. I tried inner joining the table by itself, however couldn't get the correct SQL query to do the job. How can I get a table like:

```
WHITE_WINS : 5986
BLACK_WINS : 5893
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN winner = 'white' THEN 1 END) AS WHITE_WINS,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN winner = 'black' THEN 1 END) AS BLACK_WINS
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

use `sum()`

```
select 
    sum(case when winner='white' then 1 else 0 end) as white,
    sum(case when winner='black' then 1 else 0 end) as black
from tableA
```

Comment: Cheers! Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Use below one.

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE 
            WHEN winner = 'white'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS WHITE_WINS
    ,COUNT(CASE 
            WHEN winner = 'black'
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
            END) AS BLACK_WINS
FROM ChessTable;
```